# Endocannabinoid Transporters - which ones are Likely to Exist and what is the Evidence for their Respective Existence?

Tags: proteins, neuromodulation

Endocananbinoid = Endogenous Cannabinoid or CB<sub>1</sub> and CB<sub>2</sub> ligands.

I'm asking which endocannabinoid transporters exist and could the one answering show all the evidence for the existence of the transporters they mention. For instance anandamide is suspected to have a transporter and there is some evidence for its existence, and paracetamol's chief active metabolite, AM404, appears to work by inhibiting the actions of the anandamide transporter.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you are looking for as you provide no context to your question.